# Error in vue.js (Multiple root nodes returned from render function)

Tags: json, api, vue.js, vue-component

i'm trying to generate html tags (child nodes) from JSON file with vue.js but i have this Error in console:
(Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ7Jj.png)

**javaScript Code:**

```js
const createComponent = (dNode, h) => {
  // Handle empty elements and return empty array in case the dNode passed in is empty
  if (_.isEmpty(dNode)) {
    return [];
  }

  // if the el is array call createComponent for all elements
  if (_.isArray(dNode)) {
    return dNode.map((child) => createComponent(child, h))
  }

  let children = []; 
  
  if (dNode.children && dNode.children.length > 0) {
    dNode.children.forEach((c) => {
      if (_.isString(c)) {
        children.push(c)
      } else {
        children.push(createComponent(c, h))
      }
    });
  }
  // Need to clone 
  const properties = _.cloneDeep(dNode.properties)
  return h(dNode.tagName, properties, children.length > 0? children : dNode.textNode)
}
/**
* A sample component uses the recursive createComponent to render a DOM / List of DOM nodes
*/
const MyComponent = Vue.component('my-component', {
  render: function (h) {
    return createComponent(this.nodes, h)
  },
  props: {
    nodes: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
});
 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    nodes: []
  },

  methods: {
    getChildrens() {
      this.$http.get('nodes.json').then(response => {
        this.nodes = response.body;
      }, response => {});
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getShortCodes();
    this.getChildrens();
  }
});


this is nodes.json File Content 
[
  {
    "tagName": "div",
    "children": [
      {
        "tagName": "h1",
        "textNode": "Great News"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "h3",
        "textNode": "YOU CAN CREATE VUE COMPONENTS OUT OF JSON"
      },         
      {
        "tagName": "a",
        "properties": {
          "attrs": {"href": "#"}
        },
        "textNode": "Vue.js"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "h2",
        "textNode": "Hello from the other side"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tagName": "div",
    "children": [
      {
        "tagName": "h1",
        "textNode": "another title"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "h3",
        "textNode": "third item"
      },         
      {
        "tagName": "a",
        "properties": {
          "attrs": {"href": "#"}
        },
        "textNode": "Vue.js"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "h2",
        "textNode": "Hello from the other side"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```html
This is the vue.js component which i passed nodes as a props

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <my-component :nodes="nodes"></my-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vue components can have only one root node. Your component's render function is returning multiple div tags. You can solve this by creating a single root div and append all other div to that and then return that single div. Hope it helps. refer the documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

Answer (score 1):

Your `createComponent` returns an array of `VNodes` on line `9`.

```
return dNode.map((child) => createComponent(child, h))
```

It seems that you are always passing an array of node definitions on your component and so you are generating an array of `VNodes` and Vue doesn't like you to have more than one root element in a component.

You have a couple of ways out of this:

- Wrap your array in another element. Something like this:

  ```
  render: function (h) {
    return h('div', {}, createComponent(this.nodes, h))
  },
  ```
- Generate one `MyComponent` for each top element in your JSON.

You could also change the definition of `createComponent` to always return a single component, but this could break the semantics of `createComponent` and you may not have access to that code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible with this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fragments

The plugin let's you do cool stuff like this:

```
import Fragment from 'vue-fragment'
Vue.use(Fragment.Plugin)

// or

import { Plugin } from 'vue-fragment'
Vue.use(Plugin)

// …

export const MyComponent {
  template: '
  <fragment>
    <input type="text" v-model="message">
    <span>{{ message }}</span>
  </fragment>
  ',
  data() { return { message: 'hello world }}
}
```

So the fragment itself won't be in the dom. Hope this helps you out, even though i'm quite late with this answer I see.

Comment: Q1 2020 News: In Vue3 it is actually possible to have multiple root elements!